# How to compare and export unique values from multiple csv files PYTHON

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, dataframe

Hello I am very new to Python and have attempted a search, but was unsuccessful.

I have an excel file with content as seen below

```
employee_number      email          System
807             marg.prent@test.com System1
8304            bill.riley@test.com System1 
10441           doug.wever@test.com System1
12374           Rich.flipt@test.com System2 
14012           doug.wever@test.com System2 
15906           marg.prent@test.com System2
16223           mark.johns@test.com System3
82189           doug.wever@test.com System3
86099           krish.ragg@test.com System3
86646           marg.prent@test.com System4 
87165           doug.wever@test.com System4
87844           jose.taver@test.com System4
88165           doug.wever@test.com System5
87944           jared.Rich@test.com System5 
87944           John.taver@test.com System5
```

If an employee is in more than 3 systems, I would like to remove them from the original dataframe and create a new dataFrame with those employees and the systems they were on.

So far I have:

```
`import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

EmailSysList = df[['email','System']]

for x in EmailSysList['email']:
    if EmailSysList['System'] == "System 1 ":
```

I understand this isn't much and probably the complete wrong method, but if any one can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated

Comment: would you ever have a situation where the employee would have two or more entries with the same `System`?

Comment: There will not be any duplicates of a user in the same system.

Comment: are we ignoring employee number in the aggregation? the last two have the same employee number, and `marg.prent` has multiple employee numbers?

Comment: Yes Please ignore employee numbers, they are not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's probably many ways to come up with the solution here. I will be using [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) along with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Let's first filter the dataframe to get people who are in more than 3 systems. Since you said there will be no duplicates, we can simply use counts!

```
more_than_3 = df1[df1.groupby('email')['email'].transform('count') > 3].sort_values(['email', 'System'])
# sort values is just making the output more readable and put everything in order.
# output below
    employee_number email   System
2   10441   doug.wever@test.com System1
4   14012   doug.wever@test.com System2
7   82189   doug.wever@test.com System3
10  87165   doug.wever@test.com System4
12  88165   doug.wever@test.com System5
```

Then we simply reverse the logic for the others:

```
others = df1[df1.groupby('email')['email'].transform('count') <= 3].sort_values(['email', 'System'])
# output
    employee_number email   System
14  87944   John.taver@test.com System5
3   12374   Rich.flipt@test.com System2
1   8304    bill.riley@test.com System1
13  87944   jared.Rich@test.com System5
11  87844   jose.taver@test.com System4
8   86099   krish.ragg@test.com System3
0   807     marg.prent@test.com System1
5   15906   marg.prent@test.com System2
9   86646   marg.prent@test.com System4
6   16223   mark.johns@test.com System3
```

to send these dataframes to excel you can use [`pd.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html). Furthermore, if you need them in the same workbook use the `sheetname` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is extremely helpful with my learning of Python!

Comment: Just one more quick question, in layman terms, this section of code " ['email'].transform('count') <= 3] " uses the transform function to single out the email column and the count function, counts each item to see the relation to the following expression?

Comment: the reason why i used a `transform` comes from the need to filter the original dataframe by it. from the documentation: `producing a like-indexed NDFrame`. that was the key. go ahead and simply try `df1.groupby('email').count()`. It'll give a similar answer, but without like "like-indexed" part. That's why I said there are many ways to solve this :) This is honestly one of a few times where I've used `transform`

Answer (score 0):

A groupby and count() gives you the emails you need, then you can use that Series to split the initial DataFrame.

```
morethan3emails = (df.groupby('email', as_index=False)
                     .System
                     .count()
                     .query('System > 3')
                     .email)

morethan3df = df[df.email.isin(morethan3emails)]
lessthan4df = df[~df.email.isin(morethan3emails)]
```